# jQuery>=1.9: Selecting an option in a select tag is not "fully" selected

Tags: jquery, html-select

There is really strange behavior in jQuery >= 1.9! I'm not sure if it's a bug or not!

The basic HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="1" id="opt1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" id="opt2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" id="opt3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4" id="opt4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

In jQuery <= 1.8.3, the below code works perfectly ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/evilReiko/n5MJ6/)):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#opt3').attr('selected', 'selected');// this line..
        $('#mySelect').val($('#opt3').val());   // OR this line, OR both lines, alerts will always be the same:
        alert($('#opt3').attr('selected'));     // alert "selected"
        alert($('#mySelect').val());            // alert "3"
    });
</script>
```

While in jQuery >= 1.9.0, 1st alert is "selected", and 2nd alert is "1" not "3", and Option 1 selected not Option 3! ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/evilReiko/n5MJ6/2/))

If we comment out the line `$('#opt3').attr('selected', 'selected');`, the dropdown correctly selects Option 3 but `alert($('#opt3').attr('selected'));` alerts "undefined", Option 3 do not get the "selected" attribute! The code should look like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //$('#opt3').attr('selected', 'selected');
        $('#mySelect').val($('#opt3').val());
        alert($('#opt3').attr('selected'));  // alert "undefined", no "selected" attribute set !!
        alert($('#mySelect').val());         // alert "3" correctly
    });
</script>
```

If we comment out the line `$('#mySelect').val($('#opt3').val());`, the `alert($('#opt3').attr('selected'));` alerts "selected" correctly, but value of the select is not change, alerts "1"! The code should look like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#opt3').attr('selected', 'selected');
        //$('#mySelect').val($('#opt3').val());
        alert($('#opt3').attr('selected'));  // alert "selected" correctly
        alert($('#mySelect').val());         // alert "1" !!
    });
</script>
```

**P.S.**

btw, I know some people may suggest `$('#opt3').prop('selected', true);` but that doesn't do any effect. What I'm trying to achieve, is to give Option 3 the "selected" attribute, and set the value of the select to "3". So is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Simply use `val` method `$('#mySelect').val(3);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [.prop() vs .attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: @undefined in jQuery>=1.9, `$('#mySelect').val(3);` sets the value correctly, but doesn't give Option 3 the "selected" attribute!

Comment: Please check the linked question, there is a difference between attributes and properties, DOM is based on properties, attributes are mapped to their corresponding properties on the page load and `selected` is a boolean property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mixing prop and attr

You can do:

```
$('#opt3').prop('selected', 'selected').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#mySelect').attr('value',$('#mySelect').find(':selected').val());

alert($('#opt3').prop('selected'));
alert($('#mySelect').val());
alert($('#opt3').attr('selected'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AvpLw/

Comment: Nice answer, but if you try to add `alert($('#opt3').attr('selected'));` at the bottom line of your demo, it will alert "undefined", thee is no "selected" attribute added to the option tag!

Comment: $('#opt3').prop('selected', 'selected').attr('selected', 'selected');
I updated my answer.